# Exactly what happened to Charles Xavier in this scene?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse*, we see Charles Xavier

> lose his hair during the soul transfer attempt.

Exactly how did this happen? Did Apocalypse intentionally pull them out or was something else going on here that resulted in this happening to Charles?

Comment: ...what is this.

Comment: is this all there is?

Comment: That's all I'm asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bustle explains](http://www.bustle.com/articles/162941-why-is-professor-x-bald-x-men-apocalypse-finally-reveals-the-answer):

> Well, in the second act of the film, Apocalypse kidnaps Charles.
>   Intrigued by his powers of telepathy and mind control — powers that
>   Apocalypse somehow does not yet possess — Apocalypse decides he's
>   going to transfer his consciousness and long list of powers into
>   Charles' body. The body transfer process is how Apocalypse has stayed
>   alive all these years, and how he has collected mutant powers. And, **to
>   facilitate the ritual, the mutant body Apocalypse is transferring with
>   must have a shaved head, or, in the case of Charles, lose his hair.**
>
> The scientific reason for Charles' hair loss is never explained. It's
>   likely it has something to do with Apocalypse's mutant powers that
>   manifest themselves in his blue, armored appearance. You can't wear
>   the helmet armor if you don't have a shaved head, I guess.

[Fansided links it to the transfer](https://fansided.com/2016/05/27/x-men-apocalypse-features-origin-prof-xs-baldness/):

> For some reason, whenever Apocalypse transfers his consciousness into
>   another body, doing so changes the appearance of the new host body. As
>   transfer process began, Xavier’s body started to take the form of
>   Apocalypse’s, which meant that his skin turned a little blue and his
>   cranium got a little bigger. The most notable change, however, was
>   that Xavier’s hair almost immediately fell off to match Apocalypse’s
>   hair-free scalp.

Comment: So the effects are permanent?